# How to get OS default encoding?

Tags: php, linux, encoding, character-encoding

What is the proper way of getting default OS encoding? For Linux it can be found here: /etc/sysconfig/i18n

If you think the best way is to read from that file, then can I rely it will work on all modern major Linux distributions? What about Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to detect encoding, is from the piece of text you are trying to read from.

Use mb_detect_encoding()<sup>*[[docs here]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)*</sup> function

```
$str = "....."; //use you own logic to get the text
echo mb_detect_encoding($str);
```

---

#### Adding on to @Evert

Encoding happens when characters are displayed on the screen or CLI interface. It is not OS dependent, rather content specific.

Comment: I need to save file in default OS encoding. So I will be sure that other OS applications will read that file properly. In my case it is nroff under Linux

Comment: Whenever OS opens a file through an application, the application is responsible for displaying the output as per the encoding of the file. OS, does not specifies any encoding.

Comment: Linux specifies default encoding here: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-i18n.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no true default encoding.
This can differ per terminal, application, anything really.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I seem to remember that Linux assumes UTF-8 everywhere, always, no exceptions (now if I had a reference too, it would be great...). Though of course an application might be "extra smart" and decide otherwise, but that's not "Linux".

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure. What is your goal exactly though? I have some experience with weird encoding issues so I may be able to help anyway.

Comment: And just as an example.. ext3 filenames may be *any* binary sequence, except 0x00 (I believe). It completely depends on the application to interpret that sequence, and gnome for instance assumes UTF-8 by default.

But you could even use a bell or backspace in a filename.

Comment: I am interested in _default_ OS encoding.  http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-sysconfig.html#s2-sysconfig-i18n

Comment: Ok, maybe I should rephrase.. Default encoding of what? Strings? Filenames? The console? The LANG= environment variable will serve as setting for some encoding-related api's, but you can't really call this a 'default encoding of an operating system'. Again: explain your end-purpose.. are you just looking to display this information of a statistic, or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: I am using nroff on Linux. And I need to know which encoding to save file in PHP. If file is not saved in default encoding it gives me this error: XXX
XXX WARNING: old character encoding and/or character set
XXX

Comment: Finally! Details! This would have been a great detail in your question. I don't know nroff to tell you how it works, but if it grabs the information from the environment, it's likely the LC_CTYPE env variable.. but again, this is process specific and not tied to the operating system as a whole.